# How to change the default parameter of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to simplify `df.to_csv('abc.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8')` to `df.to_csv('abc.csv')`?

I know we can use `functools.partial(function, y = 1)` for normal function, but it does not apply to pandas.

What is the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: This can be dangerous if people run you code on their machines where this change has not been made.

Comment: No, they won't mix up. Note the difference between `df.to_csv` and `df.my_to_csv` in Ami answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a very good idea, but at least don't overwrite the original method. Technically, you can add a new method like this:

```
pd.DataFrame.my_to_csv = lambda self, f_name: self.to_csv(f_name, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

You then can use it subsequently on all DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': []})
df.my_to_csv('foo.csv')
```